Delete failed entries in multipath
Due to some changes, I have to force a rescan of Fibre Channel devices on a CentOS 6 server.
This is the output of multipath -l:
(...)
36000144000000010f01c857894aede59 dm-50 EMC,Invista
size=5.0T features='1 queue_if_no_path' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
  |- 7:0:3:107 sdca 68:224  active undef unknown
  |- 4:0:3:107 sdbd 67:112  active undef unknown
  |- 7:0:4:107 sdeb 128:48  active undef unknown
  `- 4:0:7:107 sddg 70:224  active undef unknown
3600601602bd14600351eb55f237aa77d dm-5 DGC,VRAID
size=3.0T features='0' hwhandler='1 emc' wp=rw
|-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
| |- 7:0:7:39  sdq  65:0    failed undef unknown
| `- 4:0:6:39  sdei 128:160 failed undef unknown
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=enabled
  |- 7:0:0:39  sdx  65:112  active undef unknown
  `- 4:0:0:39  sdk  8:160   active undef unknown
36000144000000010f01c857894aedd26 dm-14 EMC,Invista
size=5.0T features='0' hwhandler='0' wp=rw
`-+- policy='round-robin 0' prio=0 status=active
  |- 7:0:3:94  sdba 67:64   failed undef unknown
  |- 4:0:3:94  sdad 65:208  failed undef unknown
  |- 7:0:4:94  sddb 70:144  failed undef unknown
  `- 4:0:7:94  sdcg 69:64   failed undef unknown
(...)

Running multipath -f dm-5 or multipath -w 3600601602bd14600351eb55f237aa77d does not delete the entry, not even after running multipath or restarting the multipathd service.
These entries are not present in /etc/multipath.conf.
How to delete the failed entries?

https://serverfault.com/questions/529781/multipath-device-unpresented-to-host-how-to-delete-it-from-lvm-and-the-system


I have to force a rescan of Fibre Channel devices on a CentOS 6 server.

You can do that by the (rather unintuitive):
echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/<host>/scan

Replace "<host>" with the respective FC-host.
As a side note: you may want to use more but smaller LUNs if performance is an issue. THe reason is that for a every disk a command queue is maintained and this can only hold so many entries. So, especially if you have many small disk operations (typical for e.g. databases) you may want to use rather several 1TB- or 2TB-LUNs instead of the single 5TB LUNs your system uses.

Running multipath -f <device> and then for h in /sys/class/scsi_host/host*; do echo "- - -" > /sys/class/scsi_host/$h/scan; done solved my issue.

steps for deleting 36000144000000010f01c857894aedd26 dm-14:
multipath -f 36000144000000010f01c857894aedd26

blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdba
blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdad
blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sddb
blockdev --flushbufs /dev/sdcg

echo 1 > /sys/block/sdba/device/delete
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdad/device/delete
echo 1 > /sys/block/sddb/device/delete
echo 1 > /sys/block/sdcg/device/delete

